# Flutter screen size without AppBar and BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to get the exact size of the screen without taking into account the AppBar and BottomNavigationBar

Here is the code:

```dart
double screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double height = screenSize - kToolbarHeight - kBottomNavigationBarHeight;
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: height / 2,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: height / 2,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

By doing this I am getting a height that is slighly bigger than the actual screensize withouth AppBar and BottomNavigationBar

In the screenshots below you can see how I can scroll a little bit

[image]

[image]

How can I calculate the exact height of that screen area?

Thanks for reading me and helping!

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-guide-to-using-screensize-in-flutter-a-more-readable-approach-901e82556195

Answer (score 4):

This should do it.

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight + kBottomNavigationBarHeight)
```

I think there is a default top padding you have to remove

Answer (score 1):

Getting **width** is easy but **height** can be tricky, Please follow steps it will help you..

```
   double heightWithoutappBarNavBar = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (kBottomNavigationBarHeight + kToolbarHeight);
```

Comment: Hi Babul, thanks for the post but unfortunately it doesn't help
After inspecting the padding property they all have value of 0, so there is no change on the layout

Comment: use below code. let me know it works or not...     

double heightWithoutappBarNavbar = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - (kBottomNavigationBarHeight + kToolbarHeight);

Comment: Hi Babul, that's the same as I have already, just structured in different order, it does not work :(